# File written to createWriteStream gets corrupted when listening to 'data' event on createReadStream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I have an Electron application and I have written a service to copy file using Node's `fs` module. File copy works fine when not listening to `data` event of `fs.createReadStream`, but when I add `readStream.on('data', ...` event, output file gets corrupted(Output file is always less in size than original file). This is my function code to copy files:

```
copyFile(sourcePath: string, targetPath: string): Observable<FileCopyResponseModel> {
        const copyResponse = new Subject<FileCopyResponseModel>();
        const fileSize = this.node.fs.statSync(sourcePath).size;
        const readStream = this.node.fs.createReadStream(sourcePath);
        let bytesCopied = 0;

        readStream.once("error", (err) => {
            const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
            response.is_error = true;
            response.error = err;
            copyResponse.next(response);
        });

        readStream.on('data', (buffer) => {
            bytesCopied+= buffer.length

            const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
            response.is_error = false;
            response.is_done = false;
            response.size = fileSize;
            response.size_copied = bytesCopied;
            copyResponse.next(response);
        });

        this.node.mkdirp(this.node.path.dirname(targetPath), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
                response.is_error = true;
                response.error = err;
                copyResponse.next(response);
            } else {
                const writeStream = this.node.fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
                writeStream.once("error", (err) => {
                    const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
                    response.is_error = true;
                    response.error = err;
                    copyResponse.next(response);
                });

                writeStream.once("close", (ex) => {
                    const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
                    response.is_error = false;
                    response.is_done = true;
                    response.size = fileSize;
                    copyResponse.next(response);
                });

                readStream.pipe(writeStream);
            }
        });

        return copyResponse;
    }
```

File gets copied correctly if I just comment out this section of code:

```
readStream.on('data', (buffer) => {
            bytesCopied+= buffer.length

            const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
            response.is_error = false;
            response.is_done = false;
            response.size = fileSize;
            response.size_copied = bytesCopied;
            copyResponse.next(response);
        });
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

On a Side Note copy progress is being reported correctly when listening to `data` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are trying to consume the readable stream twice. Once in the `on('data',` handler and once in `readStream.pipe(writeStream);`. The `on('data',` will consume the readable stream before you can pipe it to the write stream.

You could try replacing the line:

```
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

with

```
readStream.on('data', (buffer) => {
     bytesCopied+= buffer.length

     const response = new FileCopyResponseModel();
     response.is_error = false;
     response.is_done = false;
     response.size = fileSize;
     response.size_copied = bytesCopied;
     copyResponse.next(response);
     // new bit
     writeStream.write(buffer);
 });
```

and removing the `on('data,` from handler from above.

You can also end the writeStream when the read stream ends.

```
readStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
    writeStream.end();
});
```

Comment: How will we close writeStream in this case?